# Linux sed command replace regex string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm trying to edit a text file programmatically, which contains a line like this:

```
db.username="tata"
db.password="toto"
```

which I want to look like this:

```
db.username="fofo"
db.password="bar"
```

Here is the regex :

```
 ^\s*db.username="([^"]*)
```

when i try to use this command

```
sed -i -E '^\s*db.username="([^"]*)' 'fofo' file.txt
```

I'm getting the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `^'
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your usage of the `sed` command is incorrect. The syntax for replacements is `sed 's/regex/replacement text/' file`. Also, please indicate _how_ the solution you look for is to decide which line to act upon. Do you want to replace every occurence of `tata` with `fofo` / `toto` with `bar`, or just set the value of `db.username` to `fofo` and that of `db.password` to `bar`? Your examples implies the latter, but please specify it explicitly in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are mixing `grep`'s regex and `sed`'s substitution.

use either

```
sed -e '/db\.username/s/"[^"]*"/"foo"/' txt
db.username="foo"
db.password="toto"
```

where

- `/db\.username/` tell sed to operate on line whith db.username (`.` is special caracter in sed)
- `s` replace
- `"[^"]*"` a quote, any number of non quote, a quote by
- `"foo"`
- `/db.username/` would match `db_username`, `dbXusername` ....

or

```
sed -e 's/db\.username="[^"]*"/db.username="foo"/' txt
db.username="foo"
db.password="toto"
```

---

on a further note, `sed` can capture pattern

```
sed -e 's/db\.username="\([^"]*\)"/usename is \1/' txt
usename is tata
db.password="toto"
```

- `\(  \)` capture text
- `\1` use first captured text

`grep` can too

```
grep -Eo '"[^"]*"' txt
"tata"
"toto"
```